# fill dropdownlist using webservice in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

i want to fill the dropdown using webservice and want to pass the selected value to the controller using ajax how can i do that please help here is what i have tried so far.
here are the contents which is in my webservice is in json format.
suppose this is my webservice https://www.abc.com/webservices/radius.php?json

```
{
    "results" : [{
            "zip" : "12345",
            "city" : "delhi",
            "distance" : "0.0"
        }, {
            "zip" : "123456",
            "city" : "noida",
            "distance" : "3.1"
        }, {
            "zip" : "123457",
            "city" : "faridabad",
            "distance" : "9.1"
        }, ]
}
```

what i was trying

```
$.getJSON('https://www.abc.com/webservices/radius.php?json',function(results){ 
for (var i = 0; i <= s.results.length - 1; i++) {
      var x = new Option();
      x.text = s.results[i].city;
      x.value = s.results[i].zip;
      console.log(x);
      document.getElementById('dd').appendChild(x);
    }
}) 

<select id='dd'>
</select>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string distance)
{
    //stuffs 
}
```

please help how to call that webservice and fill that dropdown and how to pass it to the controller

Comment: Ok - What have you tried so far - there are two tasks - 1) Populate the drop down; 2) Submit that to the controller.

Have you achieved 1?

Comment: no sir nothing is working can you please help me on this. i want to populate the dropdown using this webservice

Answer (score 3):

Create a dropdown :

```
<select name="MySelect" id="MySelect">

</select>
```

now in javascript, using jquery as well:

```
var Options = "";
$.getJSON('https://www.abc.com/webservices/radius.php?json', function (response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
        Options += "<option value '" + response.results[i].zip + "'>" + response.results[i].city + "</option>";

    }
});

$("#MySelect").append(Options); // appending all options here
```

using `$.ajax` :

```
var Options = "";
$.ajax({
         url: "https://www.abc.com/webservices/radius.php?json",
         type: "get",
         success: function (response) {
               for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
                     Options += "<option value '" + response.results[i].zip + "'>" + response.results[i].city + "</option>";
                             }

            },
         error: function () {
              alert("failure");

            }
       });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0pe3m2nb/) is [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0pe3m2nb/) for populating options with javascript.

Now in Action you can get its value this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection form)
{
   string ddlValue  = form["MySelect"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: i was using ajax to do the same but in this scenario i am totally confused where and how to use ajax for that. please sir help.

Comment: @kanaksinha ``$.ajax`` will also do the same what ``$.getJSON``

Comment: i am sure it is coming on server side, in your web service this error is coming

Comment: right now i am using your jsFiddle example but i am getting the same error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: sir can you please please edit your question using ajax technique, it would be very helpful. sir please do the favour.

Comment: sir still the dropdown is not populated. i am using viewmodel and i have done something like viewModelSearch.selectedddl = Convert.ToString(form["MySelect"]);