# Bind data obtained from database table to html dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying to insert a dropdown list in my application which is in ASP.NET MVC4. I am using select tag to insert the dropdown list in index.aspx file. This dropdown should be populated based on the data that is fetched on ajax call, which is called in test.js file. So, after the ajax is called, the JSON data that is obtained is stored into a variable called combodata. My question is, how to bind this data to dropdown list that is declared in .aspx file.

Below is the code written to insert dropdown list in index.aspx file:

```
 <select id="dropdown"></select>
```

In tset.js file i am fetching flattened JSON data using the below code:

```
 var comboData; 
   $(document).ready(function (e) {    
      combodata();     
  });`

   function combodata() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'someurl',      
        success: function (data) {
             comboData = data;           
        }
     })  
  }
```

How can  comboData be binded to dropdown list? It will be of great help if someone can resolve this issue for me.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing what the shape of `comboData` is and what you are intending to do with it.

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778945/fill-dropdownlist-using-webservice-in-mvc

Answer (score 0):

please try like below.

Note: **The Value I mentioned in fr each loop denotes the value you need to display in dropdown.
eg(comboData.value)**

```
function combodata() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'someurl',      
        success: function (data) {
             comboData = data;           
             $.each(comboData, function (index, value) {
                $('#dropdown').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
             });
        }
     })  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you..

```
       $.getJSON("your url", function (data) {


            var selecttag = $('#Id_of_your_select_tag');
            $.each(return_json_obj_name, function () {
                var option = $('<option>' + this.your_return_obj_property_name + '</option>');
                selecttag.append(option);
            })
        });
```